# How to define a lune bounded by two circular arcs of equal radius?

Tags: geometry

Assume there is a circle $A$ centered at $(x, y)$. If the circle is shifted a bit to the point $(x', y')$ as in the figure, how the region shown on the right side of the figure can be mathematically / geographically defined?

What is the definition for a sphere?

[image]

Comment: what does it mean to be _mathematically defined_?

Comment: It's the [set difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Relative_complement) of the two disks, $A\setminus A'$?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the circles intersect at points $(x_1, y_1)$  and $(x_2, y_2)$ and $x_1 < x_2 $ and $y_1 > y_2$ Then the equation of area has following conditions:

$(X-x)^2 + (Y-y)^2= r^2$  for: $x_1 ≤  X ≤  x_2$ , $y_2 ≤ Y ≤  y_1$

$(X-x')^2 + (Y-y')^2=r^2$  for: $X ≥ x_2$ , $Y ≥y_2 $and $x_1 ≤ X  ≤ x_2$,$Y ≥ y_1$